# Command 'git push live master' refuses to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, web-deployment, vps

I am new to programming so sorry for the silly questions (if they might occur).

I am trying to set up automatic deployment with git with a VPS (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps).

I did all including `git remote add live ssh://user@mydomain.com/var/repo/site.git`

However, when I am trying to `git push live master`, I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host mydomain.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The problem is there in the error message: `ssh: connect to host mydomain.com port 22` it can not reach the repository. What is `mydomain.com` supposed to be?

Comment: It should be the domain of my website however, I did a mistake of setting a wrong 'user' and 'mydomain.com'. I don't know how to change it now.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out in your comment, you seem to have misconfigured your remote `live` with a wrong URL. So check the help of the corresponding subcommand on how to fix the configuration. `git help remote` shows this promising entry:

```
 git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
```

So in your case,

```
 git remote set-url live ssh://<correct-user>@<correct-path-to-repo>.git
```

will change the remote url to the correct value.

---

Alternative: to see more/all of a repository's local configuration, you can try `git config -e` and find a section like

```
[remote "live"]
    url = ssh://user@mydomain.com/var/repo/site.git
```

and modify the url there. (The file you see is just a text file located in `.git/config` within your local repo.)

Answer (score 1):

> connect to host mydomain.com port 22: Connection refused

This error directly indicates that, our local computer can't connect to the port 22 of mydomain.com.

For some "experience", this can be caused by several reasons, from "near" to "far":

1. You are not allowed to connect to a remote port of 22 from your computer. That is, the SSH port's "outgoing" direction is banned in your computer's firewall.
2. You are not allowed to connect to a remote port of 22 from your gateway. That is, for example, you are behind a proxy or company internal network, and the company or proxy, or even your ISP (though it is nearly impossible) don't allow you to connect to some domain's SSH port.
3. ~~The provider of your domain's server, for example DigitalOcean, doesn't allow you to connect to the server via port 22, though it is nearly impossible.~~
4. The configuration via webpage provided by the server provider has been set that you are disallowed to connect via port 22.
5. The firewall (for example `iptables`) of the server doesn't allow an ingoing connection of port 22.
6. Your server's SSH configuration has been set to deny connections from out of the local machine.
7. Your server has been set to listen to port 22 only via itself (which is, not an ingoing connection), that is, it just only listening to `127.0.0.1:22` not `0.0.0.0:22`.

After detecting of those possibilities, you can try to solve that issue from the cause.